# Python Regex- TypeError

Tags: python, regex, typeerror

I have written the following function:

```
def split(content):
   pattern = re.compile(r"""(\\\[-16pt]\n)(.*?)(\n\\\nthinhline)""", re.X | re.DOTALL)
   print(pattern)
   for m in pattern.finditer(content):
       print ("in for loop")
       print("Matched:\n----\n%s\n----\n" % m.group(2))
   print ("in split")
   return (0)
```

The function call:

```
def replacement(content):
   split(content)
   pattern = re.compile(r'(?<=\\\\\[-16pt]\n)([\s\S]*?)(?=\\\\\n\\thinhline)')
   content= ' '.join(re.findall(pattern, content))
   print ("in replace")
   return content
```

Content is a string.

When I try just the content of the function in a separate program , it works fine but here it is unable to go into the loop and upon further inspection- the re.compile statement isn't working as trying to print pattern gets the following error:

```
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

EDIT:

```
import re

content = """ iaisjifgrhjoigehtoi w \\
\thinhline
\\[-16pt]
  Ultraspherical
\\
\thinhline
\\[-16pt]
  & $0$
  &
\\
\thinhline
\\[-16pt]
  & $\tfrac{1}{2} \pi$
  & $2^n$
  & $0$
  &
\\
\thinhline
\\[-16pt]
  & $\tfrac{1}{2}$
  &
\\
\thinhline
\\[-16pt]
  & $(-1,1)$ & $(1 - x)^{-\frac{1}{2}} (1 + x)^{\frac{1}{2}}$
  & $\pi$
  & $-\tfrac{1}{2}$
\\
\thinhline
\\[-16pt]
  & $(0,1)$
  & $(x - x^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$
  & $\begin{cases} 2^{2n-1}, &\text{$n > 0$} \\ 1, &\text{$n = 0$} \end{cases}$
  & $-\tfrac{1}{2} n$
  &
\\
\thinhline
\\[-16pt]
  \begin{minipage}[c]{1.2in}\centering Shifted Chebyshev\\of second kind\end{minipage}
  &
\\
\thinhline
\\[-16pt]
  Legendre
\\
\thinhline
\\[-16pt]
  Shifted Legendre
\\
\thinhline
\\[-16pt]
  Laguerre
\\
\thinhline
\\[-16pt]
  Hermite
\\
\thinhline
\\[-16pt]
  Hermite
\\
\thinhline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
%
\end{onecolumn*}
"""
pattern = re.compile(r"""(\\\[-16pt]\n)    # Start. Don't technically need to capture.
                             (.*?)             # What we want. Must capture ;)
                             (\n\\\n\\\thinhline) # End. Also don't really need to capture
                          """, re.X | re.DOTALL)

for m in pattern.finditer(content):
    print("Matched:\n----\n%s\n----\n" % m.group(1))
```

Apparently, the pattern will not be matched, why is that? And how can I make a pattern that does match everything between the \[-16pt] and \ \thinhline ?

Comment: It apears that the function call to `split` does not pass string as parameter

Comment: Try `pattern.finditer(str(content)):`

Comment: It would be better to add the function call as well in the question so that others can get a better idea on where you went wrong

Comment: Content is a string. It's not necessary to know what the string is to solve this issue.

Comment: @BhargavRao is it printing "in for loop" for you?

Comment: @shr Yes and even `Matched`

Comment: @BhargavRao i have no idea why this isnt working i give up thanks anyways

Comment: @shr I ran the code with `replacement('\\\[-16pt]\nfoo\n\\\nthinhline')`

Comment: @BhargavRao it works for me when i have foo, maybe its content? content is a huge file basically converted into a string. do u think this could be the problem?

Comment: I think there are better file processing techniques than this. Do research more on them and then try to debug as to why it is going wrong. If you find out post the answer and enlighten us. As of now to sit and remotely predict as to what could have gone wrong is humanely impossible. It would be best if you try and parse each of the lines individually. A single line off the type, could have serious consequences. Do try and debug. For now (As it is dead mid-night hear) bye and all the best.

Comment: How are you sending the content and what is the content

Comment: @vks I have added the content as well as the code. Thanks.

Comment: @BhargavRao I have added the content as well as the code. Thanks.

Comment: @nu11p01n73R I  have added the content as well as the code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your regex on [Regex101.com](http://Regex101.com), and it seems it failed for a number of reasons. First, the dot `.` does not work with newlines, so it was stopping on the first line break. Second, I think you had to many slashes on the last part, `\n\\\n\\\thinhline`. It was escaping the `t`, so it was looking for a tab character. This regex worked for me: `(\\\[-16pt]\n)(.|\s)*?(\\thinhline)`.